# Laravel 5.3: Form Validation does not show errors

Tags: php, validation, laravel-5, request, laravel-request

I am trying to create a register form using Laravel.

I created a request `\App\Http\Requests\RegisterNewUserRequest`. This is the `rules()` method:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'email' => 'required|email|min:6|max:255|unique:members',
        'password' => 'required|min:6|max:16|confirmed',
        'name' => 'required|min:2|max:255|alpha',
        'surname' => 'required|min:2|max:255|alpha',

    ];
}
```

This is my Membership Controller

```
//Route::post('{locale}/create-new-user, 'MemberController@create_new_user');


public function create_new_user($locale, RegisterNewUserRequest $request)
{
    $input = $request->all();
    $input['ip'] = Request::ip();

    Member::create($input);

    return redirect("/$locale/create-account");

}
```

I violate validation rules while entering information. For example, I enter two different passwords, and enter 1 character to the email field. It does not say anything about it. Also It does not save the data into database. The page is redirected to same empty register form again.

I have got a validation summary in my view

```
...
@foreach($errors->all() as $e)
    <li>{{$e}}</li>
@endforeach
...
```

I trace data posted. It is posted. But something is weird in flow.

**EDIT**

This happens also in my contact form. If I fill the contact form properly, it sends an e-mail. But if I violate the validation rules, it doesn't say anything about validation and not send e-mail.

This is my Contact page controller

```
/**
 * @param Requests\SendMessageRequest $
 */

public function sendMessage($locale, SendMessageRequest $request)
{

    //        validation
    //        $this->validate($request,
    //            ['name' => 'required|min:3',
    //             'email' => 'required|min:5',
    //             'subject' => 'required|min:3',
    //             'message' => 'required|min:15'
    //            ]);

    $formData = $request->all();
    $formData['ip'] = Request::ip();

    Mail::send('contact.send', compact('formData'), 
                function ($message) use ($formData) {
                    $message->from('frommail@example.com', 'Example')
                            ->bcc(['bccmail@example.com'])
                            ->to('tomail@example.com')
                            ->subject($formData['subject']);
                 }
    );
}
```

**`\App\Http\Requests\SendMessageRequest`** file's **rules()** method

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'name' => 'required|min:3',
        'email' => 'required|min:5',
        'subject' => 'required|min:3',
        'message' => 'required|min:15',
    ];
}
```

Actually it was working before. After adding multi language feature validation did not worked. I do not know if there is any relation.

I suspect about use statements at the top of controllers and requests.

Comment: Can you specify the ouput? What does your $errors return? Is it an empty errorbag or does it contain  data but it is not translated? Does your validation in general still work?

Comment: Error bag is always empty

Comment: Is validation still triggered? Or are your rules not applied at all?